# Why are invalid number of elements in a structured binding checked in a concept a hard error

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
concept TwoMembers = requires { []{ auto [a1, a2] = T{}; }(); } ;

struct X { int a, b; };
struct Y { int a, b, c; };

bool ok = TwoMembers<X>;
// bool compile_error = TwoMembers<Y>;
```

My idea of concepts was that if the code in a require-expression is not valid, because type T does not satisfy the requirements, then the concept would just evaluate to false. More generally, if there are cases for which the concept evaluates to `true`, I'd expect the concept to never give a compile error, just return false for the cases where the type does not satisfy the requirements (short of pathologic cases I'm sure someone can easily devise).

Yet in this case, trying to evaluate the `TwoMembers` concept works for `struct X` but causes a compile error for `struct Y`. Is that expected or just a buggy compiler ?  (Tested on GCC 11 and recent versions of Clang and MSVC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6Yx7TTP3K)

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I am trying to make a simpler version of boost.pfr... but I am for now stuck there : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6eM8afqTn